# Converting string "3[d2[e]]" into "deedeedee"

Tags: javascript

I have a little problem. I'm working on a simple string processing program in JavaScript.

When you enter:

```
"2[a]3[bc]"
```

It would return:

```
"aabcbcbc"

"3[d2[e]]" > "deedeedee", 
"fg2[eset]3[hi]" > " fgesetesethihihi"
```

My code looks like this:

```
document.getElementById("myText").value = "String...";

function myFunction() {
  var str = document.getElementById("myText").value;
  var arr = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    var element = str[i]
    if (isNaN(element) === false) {
      arr += ".repeat(" + element + ")";
    } else if (element == "[" || element == "]") {
      arr += "'"
    } else {
      arr += element;
    }

  }
  document.getElementById("answer").value = arr;
}
```

Do you have any idea how to fix it?

Now it return: `.repeat(2)'a'.repeat(3)'bc'`

Comment: The compression language you have described is a [context-free language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_language) (or more specifically, it is a context-free language that is not a [regular language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language)). Is impossible to parse such a language without storing additional information, such as the number of opening and closing brackets seen so far. My advice would be to put down the computer, have a think about the problem, make some notes and only then come back to the code.

Comment: Sorry to say, but it amazes me how or why you would think that adding the string `".repeat("` to your text will actually help in getting the desired outcome.

Comment: He found some code somewhere that uses eval but has not figured out how it works so he couldn't copy it correctly

Comment: @AntoniBrulinski consider accepting my answer as right if it works for you

Answer (score 4):

Assuming input is always correct, You can use regular expression to get inner [ ] content and also the number of repetitions in the left. First we solve only the most intern [ ] and keep doing that until there's no more [ ] in the original string.

```js
function parseFunction(input) {
  while(input.includes("[")) {
    input = input.replace(/\d+\[[A-Za-z]+\]/g, function(s) {
      s = s.replace("]","").split("[");
      var newS = "";
      for(var i = 0; i < parseInt(s[0]); i++)
        newS += s[1]; 
      return newS;
    });
  }
  return input;
}

console.log(parseFunction("2[a]3[bc]"));
console.log(parseFunction("3[d2[e]]"));
console.log(parseFunction("fg2[eset]3[hi]"));
```

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer**: this will solution will not allow to interpret `"3[d2[e]]"`.

<s>This can be achieved</s> using methods of the `Array` object. I have provided a step by step guide on how to make it work. Also, a detailed example taking `"2[a]3[bc]"` as the starting string.

1. split the array by `]` (use the [`.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method on your `String` variable)

   ```
   [
     "2[a",
     "3[bc",
     ""
   ]
   ```
2. map each element to an array containing both the count and the string, use [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/array/map):

   ```
   [
     [
       "2",
       "a"
     ],
     [
       "3",
       "bc"
     ],
     [
       ""
     ]
   ]
   ```
3. remove the last array as it doesn't contain any information, use `slice(0, -1)`:

   ```
   [
     [
       "2",
       "a"
     ],
     [
       "3",
       "bc"
     ]
   ]
   ```
4. now it's time to combine the count and the string for each array, we do this using yet another map and applying the `String` method [`.repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat). So the function applied to each element (remember here elements are of `Array` type!) would look something like: `w => w[1].repeat(w[0].match(/\d+/)[0])`...

   `w[0].match(/\d+/)[0]` will allow to select the integer from the string:

   ```
   [
     "aa",
     "bcbcbc"
   ]
   ```
5. lastly we will join each string to make up the result, use `join('')`:

   ```
   aabcbcbc
   ```

---

Try to make it work with the above instructions. The solution is below...

```js
const convert = (array) => 
  array.split(']')
    .map(e => e.split('['))
    .slice(0, -1)
    .map(w => w[1].repeat(w[0].match(/\d+/)[0]))
    .join('')

console.log(convert("2[a]4[bc]"))
console.log(convert("2A[c]e4c[Abc]"))
```

Comment: I have made modifications to allow to `"2[a]3bb[bc]"` to work.

Comment: This doesn't work for when a non-numeric is the first character, eg the OPs example `fg2[eset]3[hi]`, nor for the nested one, `3[d2[e]]`.

Comment: True I didn't realize OP wanted that.